# Issue while running the application on Device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipod-touch

I am getting following error while running the application on the device:

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

1. IOS version - 4.2.1

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you started with the debugger attached? What does the console say?

Comment: There is nothing on the console. I am getting this at compile time only. However, this is the detail of the error: arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/abhinavgupta/iRunner/POC/Runner/PTTF/trunk/PTTFramework/build/Debug-iphoneos/libPTTLibInternal.a: No such file or directory
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: Here PTTF is a external library and in library search path I am giving its relative path from my application folder.

Comment: Well, it says what it's all about: gcc cannot find that libPTTLibInternal.a. Check the path and the directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that while importing the external library I checked in "Copy" option. We should not do that.